# slideup and slidedown with different content buggy jquery

Tags: jquery, function, slidetoggle

I have a slight glitch working with jquery .slideUp() and .slideDown() function from jquery. I'm currently showing some information in a div tag, and I have some forms that are hidden.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when I click a link, the current information shown will slideUp (to be hidden), then slideDown and a form (that was hidden).

This works, but when I do it again to show the original document and hide the form, it gets a little buggy because the form is a little longer in height-wise. So it wants to expand to the height length of the form and then jerk back to the size of the original information. I tried to show it on jsfiddle, but it seems like it works there, but it doesn't work in my site. Is there another way of doing this, maybe a better way or does anybody know what would be the problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/3jyFK/7/

Thanks

Comment: Another problem that occurs is when the Edit button is clicked rapidly.

Comment: Another pb occurs if the element you apply this on has a min-height !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `animate` method instead of `slideUp` or `slideDown`, this method is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Use .slideToggle() instead and use .stop() in conjunction with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/idmontie/3jyFK/11/

Hopefully this solves your problem.

EDIT:  There still appears to be a problem when the "Edit" text is clicked rapidly.  A way to get around this is to reset the CSS properties after each click.